# Phaser 3 ScaleManager exception

Tags: phaser-framework

I am trying to enable fullscreen in my game written in Phaser 3.
I am doing it from `Scene` class via

```
this.game.scale.startFullScreen();
```

but getting error in f12 browser console

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.game.scale.startFullScreen is not a function
    at TitleScene.<anonymous> (TitleScene.js:23)
    at InputPlugin.emit (phaser.js:2025)
    at InputPlugin.processDownEvents (phaser.js:167273)
    ...
```

In [docs](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Scale.ScaleManager.html) `ScaleManager` class has `startFullScreen` method.

Why console tells me it doesn't?

---

This is the full code of `TitleScene.js`:

```js
export class TitleScene extends Phaser.Scene {

    constructor ()
    {
        const config =
        {
            key: 'TitleScene'
        }
        super(config);
    }

    preload ()
    {
        this.load.image('Title', 'assets/Title.png');
    }

    create ()
    {
        this.background = this.add.image(960, 540, 'Title');
        this.input.manager.enabled = true;
        this.input.once('pointerdown', function () {
            this.scene.start('MainScene');
            this.game.scale.startFullScreen();  // here is the error
        }, this);
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you setting up scale manager in the game configuration like https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Scale.ScaleManager.html#toc3__anchor? If scale manager isn’t enabled, that would explain why the key startFullScreen is not populated with a function. I would also advise you enable it within the game configuration as described, a lot of add-ons that are setup while scenes are running wait for the next game tick and I’ve seen a lot of questions with that as their problem. If you need examples there should be plenty in the phaser labs. If the issue is not the config let me know.

Comment: What do you mean by talking _"**also** enable it within the game configuration "_? It is not the same thing with _"setting up scale manager in the game configuration"_?

Comment: Also I want to ask you pls. Is there any difference between declaring `type`, `width`, and `height` inside `config` or inside `scale` parameter of config?

Comment: I seems like  https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/tree/v3.22.0/src/scale/ScaleManager.js at line 480 shows it as an override for the parent container you might be scaling to. You’re right it doesn’t mention the arguments in the docs, but anywhere you might read about the scaling of the parent just remember they can be overridden from the config in scale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems prevented me from resolving this problem:

1. I followed examples from here

   https://www.phaser.io/examples/v2

   But I am using the third version Phaser. And everyone who uses the same must follow examples from here

   https://www.phaser.io/examples/v3

   You must pay attention to url while using their site with examples. Both pages are the same from the first look. But urls are different. Also there are warning after each example using the second (old) version of engine.
2. And finally this function name is not `startFullScreen` but `startFullscreen` :)